# How to animate progressbar without using width?

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that works fine. However, the progresses are animated through width, and I know it is a performance killer. How to properly animate this progressbar with a cpu-friendly technique (scaleX, etc.)?

```js
const Bar = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 12px;
`;

const Fill = styled.div<{ percentage: number }>`
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
  width: ${({ percentage }) => `${percentage}%`};
  background: red;
`;

export default function ProgressBar({ percentage }) {
  return (
      <Bar>
        <Fill percentage={percentage} />
      </Bar>
  );
}
```